# Why is it that I always get undefined from any JS object in XPiNC?

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpinc

Lotus Notes 8.5.3FP3 UP1

I initialise some code on `dojo.ready`
I hook up my table rows with an `onclick` handler:

```
dojo.query(document).delegate('tr', 'onclick', controller);
```

in my controller function I now expect to be able to do:

```
var obj = evt.target;
```

This works, I get an object in FireBug lite.

But if I try to do:

`obj.tagName` it returns undefined. In fact, it returns `undefined` regardless of what property I try to retrieve!

The same code works if I run it in the Firebug console.
It all works perfectly in every browser, including IE7 and up!

Comment: This is what I see in the console of FireBug Lite in XPiNC:
obj:[object HTMLTableRowElement]
obj.tagName:undefined

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I brought this one on myself...

XULRunner in Domino 8.5.3x is quite old and doesn't support `obj.parentElement`, so I used:

```
obj = obj.parentElement || dojo.query(obj).parent();
```

And then tried to do:

```
obj.tagName
```

See the problem?

Changing to:

```
obj = obj.parentElement || dojo.query(obj).parent()[0];
```

Solves it.